# Prove the following property of All-Pass Filters

Tags: filters, filter-design, digital-filters, allpass

If A(z) is an all-pass filter given by

$$A(z)=\frac{z^{-1}-d_1}{1-d_1 z^{-1}}$$ where $d_1$ is a real coefficient

Then prove that
$$ |A(z)|\left\{
\begin{aligned}
&<1 &|z|>1 \\
&=1 &z=1 \\
&>1 &|z|<1
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
Note: Most of the proofs available for this property assume complex coefficients but it should be valid for real coefficients too right?

Comment: Anyways, the way forward seems to be writing out what $\lvert A(z)\rvert$ is (as in: how do you calculate the absolute of a complex value?). Or, you could first simply try the $z=0$ special case (after cancelling $z^{-1}$ from your fraction). Quite possibly doing that already helps you refine your approach to ask an easier question than "prove for me that..."

Comment: The same question was also answered [here](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/q/36826/4298).

Comment: Yeah...I saw that....but the elegant solution posted by @ZR Han below perfectly answered my question....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of course it's valid for real coefficients because real number is a subset of complex number and the proof doesn't make any assumption whether the coefficient is complex or real.

For a complex $d$
$$
\begin{aligned}
|A(z)|^2 &= A(z)A^*(z) = \frac{1-d^*z}{z-d} \frac{1-dz^*}{z^*-d^*}\\
&=\frac{1-(d^*z+dz^*)+|d|^2|z|^2}{|z|^2 - (d^*z+dz^*) + |d|^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
We know that the numerator and denominator of the above equation are both non-negative. To compare it with 1, subtract denominator with numerator
$$
1 + |d|^2|z|^2 - |z|^2-|d|^2 = (1-|d|^2)+ (|d|^2-1)|z|^2 = (1-|d|^2)(1-|z|^2)
$$

If $d$ is real, then
$$
\begin{aligned}
|A(z)|^2 &= A(z)A^*(z) = \frac{1-dz}{z-d} \frac{1-dz^*}{z^*-d}\\
&=\frac{1-d(z+z^*)+d^2|z|^2}{|z|^2 - d(z+z^*) + d^2}
\end{aligned}
$$
Numerator minus denominator equals to
$$
1 + d^2|z|^2 - |z|^2-d^2 = (1-d^2)+ (d^2-1)|z|^2 = (1-d^2)(1-|z|^2)
$$

For a stable all-pass filter we have $|d|<1$, so the sign of subtraction is determined by $1-|z|^2$, i.e., if

1. $|z| > 1$, $|A(z)| < 1$
2. $|z| = 1$, $|A(z)| = 1$ (that's an all-pass!)
3. $|z| < 1$, $|A(z)| > 1$

It seems there is something wrong with your question, it is easy to see that $|A(z)|=-1/d\neq 0$ when $z=0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @ZR Han!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Orpheus Glad to help :)

Comment: I think there is a small correction....in the second equation I think the numerator should be $1-dz-d^{*}z^{*}+|d|^2|z|^2$

Comment: @Orpheus corrected. The second equation is correct. When the coefficient is complex, the transfer function of an all-pass filter should be $H(z)=(1-d^*z)/(z-d)$ so that the zero and pole are reciprocal.

Comment: ...noted...thanks a million!